# Faker-cs Package for .NET: Usage Example?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking

I installed the **Faker Port for C#** (https://github.com/oriches/faker-cs) in my project but the project site doesn't give examples of usage.

Can someone post some examples of basic mock data generation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, I'm using a project that uses MVC4, EF Code First and Automatic Migrations. So if you're using the same, your `Migrations\Configuration.cs` file should be like this:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

...
```

For single elements, the example is trivial:

```
protected override void Seed(MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext context)
    {
        context.Customers.AddOrUpdate(
            c => c.Name,
            new Customer { Name = Faker.Name.FullName() }
        );

        context.SaveChanges();

        ...
```

For a defined number of elements, I liked the idea of using a lambda expression, like [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) (for Ruby on Rails) does. In another question I made ([DbMigrations in .NET w/ Code First: How to Repeat Instructions with Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518894/dbmigrations-in-net-w-code-first-how-to-repeat-instructions-with-expressions)) the answer uses `Enumberable.Range()` to specify the elements amount:

```
protected override void Seed(MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext context)
{
    context.Companies.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Name,
            Enumerable.Range(1, 10).
            Select( x => new Company { Name = Faker.Company.Name() }).ToArray()
    );

    context.SaveChanges();
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a scarcity of resources available, yet [this article](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.in/2012/03/faking-data-in-wp7-and-other-net.html) seems to be what one would expect.

Also try using the Assembly/Object Browser to look at available resources (e.g. which `Classes`, `Methods` and so on are contained in the library). Furthermore, the library contains `NUnit` tests, thus a [look at the tests](https://github.com/jonwingfield/Faker.Net/tree/master/Faker.Net.NUnit.Tests)' code may also prove beneficial.

As Faker.NET is a port of the Ruby library called [ffaker](https://github.com/EmmanuelOga/ffaker), one may also imply that the code is similar in intentions, therefore one could also use ffaker's unit tests as a small reference.

Comment: The Faker.Net examples are too basic for mock data generation. Thanks for the links. I'll post an answer based in some examples I've developed in the past days.