# DbMigrations in .NET w/ Code First: How to Repeat Instructions with Expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mocking

My project uses ASP.NET MVC4, C#, EF Code First and the Faker-cs Package (https://github.com/oriches/faker-cs). I wrote this example to test how Faker-cs works in my `Migrations\Configuration.cs` file:

```
protected override void Seed(MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext context)
{
    context.Companies.AddOrUpdate(
        p => p.Name,
        new Company { Name = Faker.Company.Name() }
    );
}
```

How can I repeat `n` times the object generation?

```
protected override void Seed(MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext context)
{
    context.Companies.AddOrUpdate(
        p => p.Name,
        // Repeat insertion of new Companies (i.e., 10)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a LINQ lambda expression, something like this should work:

```
protected override void Seed(Fideli100.Models.Fideli100Context context)
{
    context.Companies.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Name,
            Enumerable.Range(1, 10).
            Select( x => new Company { Name = Faker.Company.Name() }).ToArray()
    );
}
```